# Load images using webpack and react

Tags: webpack

I cant figure out how to get images to load using webpack and React. I have tried many options and it always says that the hashed name of the file cant be found. I am using file-loader right now.

webpack.config

```
{
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
```

tried as css background

```css
#box {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: solid black;
  background: url("./images/grape.png");
}
```

Also tried in my index.js file

```
import img from "./images/grape.png";
...
...

render(){
return(

 <img src={img} />

)}
```

This is the error i always get
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/1588566d908ab07815178f219404856d.png 404 not found.

Comment: Try as `/grape.png` in your css

Comment: grape.png:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/itemmanager/frontend/src/components/items/images/grape.png

Comment: I think the issue is its trying to call the image from a folder /images/ that is in front of my whole app, which doesnt exists

Comment: Yes it feels like it. I don't see anything wrong in your code. Try without the brackets, but that shouldn't be making a difference. Make sure the resolution of the path for your images folder is correct. I see it's trying to get it from the /src/ while it should be a shorter url that looks in a dist folder.

Comment: Oh wait, did you try calling it as `/grape.png` in your css or did you change your `index.js`?

Comment: i tried changing it to /grape/png, doesnt work. When importing into the js file, my npm terminal says this... 1588566d908ab07815178f219404856d.png   535 KiB          [emitted]

Comment: can you show your webpack.config?

Comment: module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};

Comment: I believe the problem is babel loader, I was able to get the image to work by using url-loader. Thank you @jabberwocky for your time.